# Change color of diffrent sections of pre

Tags: html, css, colors, pre

I am trying to make some ASCII art different colors in different sections.

Example the color of the ghosts and the text be different:

```
<pre>
 .-') _     ('-.    .-')    .-') _    
(  OO) )  _(  OO)  ( OO ). (  OO) )   
/     '._(,------.(_)---\_)/     '._  
|'--...__)|  .---'/    _ | |'--...__) 
'--.  .--'|  |    \  :` `. '--.  .--' 
   |  |  (|  '--.  '..`''.)   |  |    
   |  |   |  .--' .-._)   \   |  |    
   |  |   |  `---.\       /   |  |    
   `--'   `------' `-----'    `--'    
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Umm.. Since the ghosts' and texts' heights were unequal, that's really hard(merely impossible) to do.

But here's a (semi)solution that's close to your requirements.

Use the combination of `linear-gradient` and `background-clip` properties.

Try this

```css
pre{background: -webkit-linear-gradient(blue 44px, red 10%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;}
```

```html
<pre>
 .-') _     ('-.    .-')    .-') _    
(  OO) )  _(  OO)  ( OO ). (  OO) )   
/     '._(,------.(_)---\_)/     '._  
|'--...__)|  .---'/    _ | |'--...__) 
'--.  .--'|  |    \  :` `. '--.  .--' 
   |  |  (|  '--.  '..`''.)   |  |    
   |  |   |  .--' .-._)   \   |  |    
   |  |   |  `---.\       /   |  |    
   `--'   `------' `-----'    `--'    
</pre>
```

A codepen: https://codepen.io/Ev1tw1n/pen/NEoxRe

Answer (score 0):

You can consider multiple background and you will be able to easily adjust color of each part of the `pre` element. You may also consider the `em` unit so that it will work with any value of `font-size`:

```css
pre {
  background:
    linear-gradient(blue, blue) 0 0/5em 5em,
    linear-gradient(red, red) 0 100%/5em calc(100% - 5em),
    linear-gradient(green, green) 5em 0/10em 3em,
    linear-gradient(orange, orange) 5em 100%/10em calc(100% - 3em),
    linear-gradient(purple, purple) 15em 0/5em 5em,
    linear-gradient(#22eeff, #22eeff) 15em 100%/10em calc(100% - 5em);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<pre>
 .-') _     ('-.    .-')    .-') _    
(  OO) )  _(  OO)  ( OO ). (  OO) )   
/     '._(,------.(_)---\_)/     '._  
|'--...__)|  .---'/    _ | |'--...__) 
'--.  .--'|  |    \  :` `. '--.  .--' 
   |  |  (|  '--.  '..`''.)   |  |    
   |  |   |  .--' .-._)   \   |  |    
   |  |   |  `---.\       /   |  |    
   `--'   `------' `-----'    `--'    
</pre>
<pre style="font-size:20px">
 .-') _     ('-.    .-')    .-') _    
(  OO) )  _(  OO)  ( OO ). (  OO) )   
/     '._(,------.(_)---\_)/     '._  
|'--...__)|  .---'/    _ | |'--...__) 
'--.  .--'|  |    \  :` `. '--.  .--' 
   |  |  (|  '--.  '..`''.)   |  |    
   |  |   |  .--' .-._)   \   |  |    
   |  |   |  `---.\       /   |  |    
   `--'   `------' `-----'    `--'    
</pre>
```